# Creating related Models on Laravel/Eloquent relations with primary key type UUID

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, uuid

Laravel: 7; PHP: 7.4/8.0

In my project I have two related models: `User` and `TimeAccount`. Both use UUID for their primary key, the key name is still `id`.

**Migrations:**

```php
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            // snip...
        });
    }
    
    // snip...
}
```

```php
class CreateTimeAccountsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('time_accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->foreignUuid('user_id')->nullable()->constrained();
            // snip...
        });
    }
    
    // snip...
}
```

**Models:**

```php
class User
{
    use IsIdentifiedByUuid;

    protected $keyType = 'string';

    public function timeAccount()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(TimeAccount::class);
    }

    // snip...
}
```

```php
class TimeAccount
{
    use IsIdentifiedByUuid;

    protected $keyType = 'string';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    // snip...
}
```

**IsIdentifiedByUuid** Trait:

```php
trait IsIdentifiedByUuid
{
    protected static function bootIsIdentifiedByUuid()
    {
        static::creating(fn ($model) => static::isIdentifiedByUuidCreatingHandler($model));
        static::saving(fn ($model) => static::isIdentifiedByUuidSavingHandler($model));
    }

    public function initializeIsIdentifiedByUuid()
    {
        $this->keyType = 'string';
    }

    protected function getUuidColumn(): string
    {
        return property_exists($this, 'uuid_column') ? $this->uuid_column : 'id';
    }

    protected static function getNewUuid(): UuidInterface
    {
        $columnName = app(static::class)->getUuidColumn();
        $tableName = app(static::class)->getTable();
        $columnDescriptor = "$tableName.$columnName";
        $uuid = "";
        $query = \DB::table($tableName)
            ->select($columnDescriptor)
            ->where($columnDescriptor, $uuid);
        $attempts = 0;
        do {
            if ($attempts >= \App\Constants\Uuid::MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
                throw new UuidMaxGeneratorAttemptsExceededException();
            }
            $uuid = Str::uuid();
            $attempts++;
        } while ($query->setBindings([ $uuid->toString() ])->count() > 0);

        return $uuid;
    }

    /**
     * Handles the creation of a model.
     * - Generates new UUID if the UUID column is empty and auto-increment is enabled
     *
     * @param Model $model
     * @throws \App\Exceptions\UuidMaxGeneratorAttemptsExceededException
     */
    protected static function isIdentifiedByUuidCreatingHandler(Model $model)
    {
        $columnName = $model->getUuidColumn();
        if ($model->getIncrementing() && !$model->{$columnName}) {
            $uuid = static::getNewUuid();
            \Log::debug(
                "IsIdentifiedByUuid [CREATING]:" .
                " Generating new UUID for `" . get_class($model) . ": $uuid`"
            );
            $model->{$columnName} = $uuid->toString();
        } else {
            \Log::debug(
                "IsIdentifiedByUuid [CREATING]:" .
                " Using existing UUID for `" . get_class($model) . ": $model->{$columnName}`"
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the saving of a Model.
     * - Prevents changes to the UUID column
     * - Rolls back changed value to old value
     *
     * @param Model $model
     */
    protected static function isIdentifiedByUuidSavingHandler(Model $model)
    {
        $columnName = $model->getUuidColumn();
        $originalUuid = $model->getOriginal($columnName);
        if (!is_null($originalUuid) &&
            $originalUuid !== $model->{$columnName}
        ) {
            \Log::debug(
                "IsIdentifiedByUuid [SAVING]:" .
                " Prevented change of UUID for `" . get_class($model) . ":$originalUuid`"
            );
            $model->{$columnName} = $originalUuid;
        }
    }
}
```

**Now the Problem:**

Within an user-observer on the created hook I'm doing this:

```
$userTimeAccount = $user->timeAccount()->create([
    // snip...
]);
```

So far - before switching to UUID instead of integer keys - everything worked fine! As far as I know creating the related model before the user-model has been saved (and obviously before auto-inc was triggered) is something that is explicitly allowed by eloquent/Laravel (though I can not find the section of the docs).

After switching to UUID this is not working anymore and I'm getting an SQL error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`laravel_torus`.`time_accounts`, CONSTRAINT `time_accounts_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `time_accounts` (`time_account_type_id`, `balance`, `borrow`, `user_id`, `id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (3, 0, 0, 0, a995807b-b7e1-4af3-96de-7c48187f943d, 2021-07-09 12:54:25, 2021-07-09 12:54:25))

SQL beautified:

```sql
insert into `time_accounts` 
    (`time_account_type_id`, `balance`, `borrow`, `user_id`, `id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
    values 
    (3, 0, 0, 0, 'bad86e70-7496-4b42-b2a1-5cc3c5a4d06c', '2021-07-09 11:19:17', '2021-07-09 11:19:17');
```

Somehow Laravel tries to insert zero (integer) for the Foreign key which will obviously not work. I even tried setting `keyType` to `'string'` manually without effect.

*Where am I wrong?*

---

**EDIT:** It seems like there is a race condition. The created hook of the Observer will be triggered before the created hook of the `User` model. This leads to the missing ID - the ID is present when using integer and auto increment, just as it should.

Comment: what are you inserting inside the create array ?

Comment: the other columns for the model, just integer/text columns and one integer fk, I removed them from the example because I think they are not necessary for the problem.

Comment: aren't you just missing an user_id? should it be null?

Comment: @Tropus thanks for the suggestion, I can try setting user_id manually to null. Maybe this solves the problem - at least for that special case where the FK-column is nullable. However in other cases this would probably not work since most FK-columns in my application are not nullable. - But I can only try that on monday so it might take a while.

Comment: @Tropus unfortunately the suggested approach did not solve the problem.

Comment: That's a shame, the only other thing I can see is that you're not overwriting the default boot method, so it might not hit your custom handling of the primary key when you're creating a model, unless you've got some code that does that which you haven't shown here.

Comment: I'm using a 'bootable' trait, its Laravel specific. Have a look at the `bootIsIdentifiedByUuid` method. Also this is an 'initializable' trait, indicated by the `initializeIsIdentifiedByUuid` method. Laravel will search for methods named `boot<MyTraitName>` and `initialize<MyTraitName>` on models and automatically call them on boot/construct. As pointed out in the answer this works for Postgres. I prefer Postgres more and more anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR

> I was not able to solve this with MySQL and switched to Postgres SQL.
>
> **DONT USE *UUID* WITH MYSQL** unless you are, absolutely sure that: 1. you need to and 2. the performance impact will be negligible!

---

I really can not explain how this error is happening at all. The ID in question already exists (looking with the debugger into the `$attribnutes` array of the model), still Laravel will return integer `0` when calling `$user->id`.

While investigating the problem I noticed that Laravel is creating String columns for the UUID instead of binary (wich is what I would have expected). Since string comparism is quite cost intensive compared to integer/binary comparism I decided to abandon MySQL. UUID's are mandatory for this project and a shift to another DBMS, away from MySQL, in future was already intended.

Postgres SQL supports a special Column type `uuid` wich will be used by Laravel if a UUID column is defined. This does not only store and compare the ID as binary but also checks for format and unique values, meaning you can not enter an invalid UUID by accident like in MySQL regular sting columns wich seem to have no checks at all apart from `not null` and `unique`.